# Is Hyotan Rozu or Calabash Rose a bad publishing name?

Tags: poetry, pseudonym

Opening question got too long so I shortened it drastically, I like the name calabash rose as a publishing name but it struck me as gimmicky so I played around on google translate a bit and settled on Hyotan Rozu.

This is Japanese and I'm nothing close to Japanese so I'm not sure if it's bad or misleading to use it on the cover of a poetry book, especially considering Japan's well known history with poetry.

Is Calabash Rose ok/better as a Pseudonym?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm not sure we can give you advice about whether a particular pseudonym is good or bad, as that's a subjective judgement and we don't do that sort of thing here, but we *can* address your concern about whether a non-Japanese person adopting a Japanese pseudonym would be a bad idea.

Comment: Oh, I thought there might be a sort if consensus on what sort of pseudonyms were popular or mocked. I would like advice on the second part of the question

Comment: See [Would there be any problems with choosing a pseudonym of another ethnicity and sex?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/24374/34330)